# A problem using systemctl to auto start on boot a service

Tags: linux, systemd, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to auto start a program using `systemctl` in Raspberry pi 4.

```
[Unit]
Description = Connect to server automatically on boot
After = multi-user.target
 
[Service]
Type = idle
ExecStart = /usr/bin/sudo /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /home/pi/E6101/AV308XC/AV308XC.dll > /home/pi/log2.txt 2>&1
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the service file that I want to operate. I add `> /home/pi/log2.txt 2>&1` to check if it works well or what is wrong but even `log2.txt` file wasn't created.

So I check the status of my service file `dotnet_auto.service`. Below is the result of it.

```
  $ sudo systemctl status dotnet_auto.service

● dotnet_auto.service - Connect to server automatically on boot
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dotnet_auto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2021-11-09 12:14:01 KST; 2min 34s ago
  Process: 741 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /home/pi/E6101/AV308XC/AV308XC.dll > /home/pi/log2.txt 2>&1 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]:    at AV308XC.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\KDSONG\Project\SKD\2021-08 - AVISS - MEMS SENSOR\AV308XC\Program.cs:line 26
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 sudo[741]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 systemd[1]: dotnet_auto.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 systemd[1]: dotnet_auto.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
11월 09 12:14:01 EMTRP4DEV1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Connect to server automatically on boot.
```

The command at `ExecStart` works well if I run manually on the console. I've tried several options (maybe not all of them...) for `Type` and `Restart` sections. Result comes out slightly different but mostly the same.

If someone knows anything about this please leave a comment or answer the question. If you think the code of the program that I want to operate seems to be the problem let me know what it is. However I'm sorry to say this but I cannot show you the code... I do have the source code but it's not mine... Anyway except for the source code if there's something you need to check leave a comment.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that your C# program is crashing in line 26 in Program.cs (well, not exactly there, but in the code that is called from that location.) That the program runs when started manually can be because of something different in the environment: different working directory, different user, some environment variable is set in one case and not the other, etc. From the log I would guess this has something to do with whether a configuration file is readable or not.

Comment: Oh...problem solved!! I've changed the command to this and it worked!

*su - pi -c "/usr/bin/nohup /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet home/pi/E6101/AV308XC/AV308XC.dll & &> /home/pi/log1.txt"*

Comment: However the purpose of the program is to connect to the cloud server and repeat the cycle of sending data and recieving respond...But it ends before that... When I reboot the device and check the process, 3sec to prepare for the start of the command and 1sec to try to connect and it dies after 1sec... I don't know if it's because even nohup can't keep the process run or hmm... I don't know.

Comment: You should use the `User=` setting in the unit file instead of `su`-ing to the desired user

Comment: Thanks. That works too. But nothing has changed...I put

`Restart` = always
RestartSec = 5`

in the service section and it does work. However as the connection process keeps dying the command restarts every 5sec!!

Comment: I am still of the opinion that the problem lies in the C# program itself, and your time is better spent trying to debug it rather than trying to tweak your systemd unit file. Maybe you could add some exception handlers to catch errors and exit gracefully with a log message instead of crashing?

Comment: Well...that seems to be the best way now. About that I have some questions. I heard that the program worked well on Raspberry pi 3 using rc.local file instead of systemd. Of course I've already tried it but didn't work. So is there anything you can think of where to find it or what kind of problem could it be? And as you know the command works well on manually so I have to use `systemctl start` to find the error which doesn't work either...But I think that's because of the restart option the process is still alive(?).

Comment: Anyway can gdb debug this? I've only used gdb on c program and that wasn't heavy as this one. Only some c files and libraries, which doesn't need`.exe` or `.dll` files...

Comment: You already got one clue: the call trace starting at line 26 in `Program.cs`. Add a exception handler there and you may be able to get some info on the error into a log file. That the program runs when started in some other way does not prove much. The program may get confused for a number of reasons: directories or files that don't exist, standard input being connected to `/dev/null` (like systemd does by default), etc.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you for answering my questions!